# Tablet listed under adb devices, but not under lsusb while in recovery

Tags: adb, linux, bootloader, fastboot

I am working with a Gemini devices GEM1000 tablet, I have performed all the steps to get adb working, and the device shows up under 'adb devices' so I go to the bootloader with 'adb reboot bootloader' and once in the bootloader, the device can no longer be descovered with 'adb devices' or 'fastboot devices'

checking 'lsusb' the tablet is not showing up as connected, although if I select "appply update with ADB" it then shows up as '2837487629 sideload' under 'adb devices' and then shows up in lsusb again

The recovery says 'Android System recovery <3e>' and 'Recovery system v4.2.41' in case that matters. Could it be possible I need to flash a different recovery? if so are there any generic recoveries?(since I doubt this generic tablet has any custom ones)

How do i get the device to show up in 'fastboot devices' once I enter recovery mode?

Comment: IMHO fastboot is a separate mode (I've never used it, so I'm not 100% sure). Keep in mind that devices might present different IDs when booted normal, in recovery, or in fastboot mode, so you might have to set up separate UDEV rules for each of those.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much for the UDEV rules, which is why I tried lsusb to find what the info was but it isn't there. In the case of fastboot vs bootloader I am not sure, from what I understand, while in the bootloader it should be visible under 'fastboot devices'because oem unlock tutorials say the steps are 'adb reboot bootloader' then 'fastboot oem unlock' I don't think this device has a separate fastboot mode, if it does have a separate fastboot mode, how do you enter fastboot vs the bootloader

Comment: You're correct: "bootloader" should be "fastboot mode" (adb might not find the device there) – while in recovery and normal mode fastboot shouldn't detect the device (but adb should). Anyway, in all 3 modes the device should be visible via `lsusb`. I got confused by your last paragraph I guess. And yes: `<3e>` is the "stock recovery", and there are several [custom recoveries](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info) available, e.g. CWM, TWRP, Philz, AmonRa, and more. Not sure if they have any effect on bootloader/fastboot mode, so I better leave that to someone else now :)

Comment: Sorry to be confusing the problem is that when in the bootloader, when going through power+vol-down+vol+up, when plugged in shows nothing under lsusb. But when going to the bootloader with 'adb reboot bootloader' it now shows up in lsusb but the screen is black and 'fastboot devices' shows nothing. The device is Bus 001 Device 009: ID 2207:300b so I added a UDEV rule: SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2207", Mode="0666"

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the stock recovery (as pointed out in the comments) doesn't come with ADB enabled, which is why your device is neither shown with `adb devices` nor with `lsusb` when you've booted it into `<3e>`. The only way around this (if you really need to access the tablet via ADB while booted into [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode)) is flashing it with a custom recovery, such as [clockworkmod-recovery](/questions/tagged/clockworkmod-recovery) or [twrp](/questions/tagged/twrp) – which again requires your bootloader to be unlocked (see: [bootloader-unlock](/questions/tagged/bootloader-unlock)).

Note that the recovery image must match your device, so you cannot just pick any. I'm not sure whether there's any custom recovery available for the GEM1000; good points to check that out is looking at [XDA-Developers](http://forums.xda-developers.com/) and the websites of the corresponding recoveries.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a second answer but I think Izzys answer is not getting the point perfectly.

First of all your Question:

> How do i get the device to show up in 'fastboot devices' once I enter
>   recovery mode?

This won't happen at all. Recovery and fastboot are different things. 
Fastboot is mostly part of the bootloader of your device which is probably a binary blob which basically means it is not open at all and could be hard to exchange in order to have a bootloader which supports fastboot correctly.

Recovery is usually a lightweight android system by itself which is used for "recovery" functions. It often comes with it's own kernel apart from the main android system so it will still boot if your main android system is not booting.

tl;dr: Probably your device bootloader does not support fastboot which would mean you can't use the fastboot method.

Questions you should ask yourself:

- Did fastboot ever work with any other device from your current setup?
- Is there a forum entry or anything which confirms that fastboot ist working with your device?